# NSPredicate and CoreData key coding compliance issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to filter through my CoreData for a matching Name, and if it exists ignore it, or else add the new Name to Core Data. The issue I am having should be a simple one but I can't quite figure it out.

[here's a link to a shot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyU7i.png)

the value in my coredata is "trackName" of type String, but I keep getting the following exception:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key trackName.'

How should I proceed? Is it not clear that the Fetch Request is for a String?

Comment: Don't post images. Post code! The solution is pretty simple but nobody is willing to retype the code from the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will post code next time I (inevitably) ask for more help haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `value(forKey:)` on an instance of `NSFetchRequest`, but that key is only defined for `NSManagedObject` instances that represent your `Track` entity.

A fetch request is an object that represents a Core Data query. Based on your code, I'm assuming you are trying to ensure that the `trackName` property is unique across all `Track` entities. You need to `execute()` the fetch request and check to make sure the array returned by that method is empty.

Comment: Thanks @DaveWeston, this really helps. You're right that I was trying to ensure that I wasn't entering duplicate Track entities if the 'trackName' already exists. Because I'm new to core data (coding in general to be honest), I wasn't clear on how to access the bits retrieved in my query

Answer (score 0):

Please updating your code to this one and try

```
if result == nil {
   //result is null because you entered string is not found the valueForkey is also not found in your result
    print("new entry")
}else{
    print("added")
}
```